# Is there a solution for scanning webserver files for malicious code?

Tags: security, webserver, javascript

I have seen several times people move code into web servers now that had malicious code embedded into their HTML, php and other documents. These then get served up from the new server until they are detected. Other times, they don't update their wordpress instance and some code injection nastiness happens.

Is there some solution I can run on my own web servers that will scan for code like known javascript, etc. exploits in all files being served by my webserver? Does ClamAV do that? I've also seen maldetect, but I haven't seen anything that seems to be looking at helping sysadmins with web servers and I wonder if those tools are sufficient.